# Django Page not found (404)

Tags: django

I'm designing a photo app .

I get this error every time I view an uploaded picture on my admin page.

```
 Page not found (404)
 Request Method:    GET
 Request URL:   http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/images/California_Poppy.jpg

 Using the URLconf defined in mysite.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

     ^polls/
     ^admin/
     ^cool/
     ^forum/
     ^register/

 The current URL, media/images/California_Poppy.jpg, didn't match any of these.
```

My current settings are :

```
 MEDIA_ROOT = 'C:/djcode/mysite/photo'


 MEDIA_URL = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/'
```

I reckon the problem is with these settings. I'm using window btw

Comment: How are our views set up? urls.py? anything?

Comment: Their none. but i'm just displaying pictures from my admin page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/howto/static-files/#serving-other-directories) have a solution for you to serve media in development.  Usually in production you alias your media directory to be served directly from your web server to be more efficient.  To serve in development, the docs show two different solutions.  You can check out the provided link to read the docs and figure out which one would be better for you.

```
from django.conf import settings

# ... the rest of your URLconf goes here ...

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += patterns('',
        url(r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {
            'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT,
        }),
   )
```

OR

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # ... the rest of your URLconf goes here ...
) + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```